# Is Pohlig-Hellman Cipher the only option?

Tags: discrete-logarithm, commutative-encryption, pohlig-hellman-cipher

I am looking for a cipher which would allow something like this: ***E(E(M, a), b) = E(M, ab)***, where ***a*** and ***b*** are encryption keys, and ***ab*** is a combination of the keys that is impractical to separate into ***a*** and ***b***.

So far, the only cipher I could find that would work like this is Pohlig-Hellman Exponentiation Cipher. But as I understand, it has the following drawbacks:

1. It is slow - though, this is not really a concern for me
2. I can't find any actual implementations of the cipher. It shouldn't be too difficult to implement from scratch, but still...

Is there another cipher that can accomplish the same thing?

Comment: Hi Irakliy and welcome. Could you extract that last part of your question about the sizes and create a different question for it? It seems rather distinct from the main question.

Comment: Thanks! Sure thing - I just removed the last part of the question. I'll create a separate question later if Pohling-Hellman is indeed the only thing I can use.

Comment: Why do you have such a requirement? Do you need the combination ab to be commutative? ab=ba?

Comment: This is for zero-knowledge info sharing [system](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/58089/information-sharing-using-interactive-zero-knowledge-system) I'm designing. The combination doesn't really need to be commutative, though Pohlig-Hellman is.

Comment: [Key-homomorphic encryption](https://eprint.iacr.org/2014/356) allows you to compute $\mathsf{Enc}_k(m)\stackrel{f}{\mapsto} \mathsf{Enc}_{f(k)}(m)$ for any arbitrary computable $f$. This is *close* to what you want, but I'd imagine it has similar issues as Pohlig-Hellman (although I haven't checked).

Answer (score 1):

If you define $E_a(M) = M \oplus  a$ then the key $ab$ can also be defined as $a \oplus b$ as follows:

$E_b(E_a(M)) = (M \oplus a) \oplus b$

$E_{ab}(M) = M \oplus (a \oplus b)$

However using the same key and/or message more than once in XOR will leak the other one. So I think it's potentially not what you're looking for.

As far as I know, SRA is also a variant, where you get regular RSA where both parties use the same modulus (and prime numbers) and create their own encryption, decryption exponents; and keep it secret. This way you achieve the same commutativity as in PH.

Comment: $E(M,k) = M \oplus  k$ uses the same math as the One Time Pad. Problem is (as noted in the answer) that when considered a cipher, $E$ is insecure under even Known Plaintext attack. The OTP is not a cipher, or is insecure; that's depending on if "One Time" is applied, or not.